# Accessing a File Upload Window - Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to upload a file and proceed further with my testing but the issue here is that the solution proposed by many on this site doesn't seem to work for me.

Given below is the window.

[image]

I'm now trying to provide a path directly instead of clicking the file input (which by the way, was the solution provided on several stackoverflow pages) on the following page.

https://huew.co/discover/

```
newip = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/form/input")
newip.send_keys("D:\p1.png")
```

It doesn't seem to pass the path D:\p1.png
Can someone please help me with this ?

I do not want to use AutoIt, I'd like to achieve this file upload by making use of selenium and python. I believe it should be possible but I'm having a hard time achieving it. I've even tried using ActionChains but that didn't resolve the issue either.

My OS is Windows 10, browse is Google Chrome (Version 71.0.3578.98)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the error `File not found` you need to escape the backslash `\` with `\\` or using slash `/` and if you get error cannot locate the element add wait using `WebDriverWait` but I didn't get this error.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# wait max 10 seconds
newip = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser, 10).until(
    lambda chrome_browser: chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/form/input")
)
newip.send_keys("D:\\p1.png")

# click the Submit using javascript
driver.execute_script('''
   document.querySelector('button.desktop-photo-submit.ng-scope').click()
''')
```

Comment: The snippet of code you've pasted in your answer is working i.e. it's able to upload the file located at D:\\p1.png (or really any location for that matter) ?

Comment: location is matter, the file must exist.

Comment: Yes the file does exist on my setup but it still doesn't lead to the file being selected for upload and the "SUBMIT" button becoming visible. Does the fact that control is handed over to the native OS window affect Selenium ? I've heard this is a real possibility.

Comment: the element `#preloader` overlapped the button and prevent selenium to click it. edited the answer, take a look.